# Delegate in a where clause

Tags: linq, delegates, where-clause, lambda

I can define a delegate and write the query like this.

```
Func<string, bool>   filter  = s => s.Length == 5;

IEnumerable<string> query = names.Where(filter)                                  
                                 .Select(x => x.ToUpper());
```

My question is, if the `Func<T, TResult>` is a delegate taking a string as argument and returning a bool, why cannot I say:

```
delegate bool D(string s);
D d = new D(delegate(string s) { return s.Length == 1; });

IEnumerable<string> query = names.Where(d).Select...
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because they are different types.

A shorter version giving the same kind of error:

```
delegate bool D(string s);
delegate bool F(string s);

D d = new D(delegate(string s) { return s.Length == 1; });
F f = d;
```

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'Program.D' to 'Program.F'

And the extension method `Where` is defined as

```
Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate);
```

So you need a `Func<string, bool>` and `D` is similar but not compatible.

Answer (score 3):

It's because two different delegate types (and `Func<TSource, TResult>` is a delegate type, too) are considered different types, even if their signature is the same.

Answer (score 3):

These are not the same type, even if they are compatible.

You need to "cast" it:

```
var query = names.Where(new Func<string, bool>(d))
```

I usually just do:

```
var query = names.Where(x => d(x))
```

Comment: The only person that actually helped the SO accomplish their objective lol